# curl php HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to send a request using `cURL` and `PHP` and it throws an error.

> HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

I am sending `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` like this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
```

`cURL` info printed with `curel_version()` is

```
Array
(
    [version_number] => 475136
    [age] => 4
    [features] => 11518877
    [ssl_version_number] => 0
    [version] => 7.64.0
    [host] => x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
    [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/1.0.2q
    [libz_version] => 1.2.11
    [protocols] => Array
        (
            [0] => dict
            [1] => file
            [2] => ftp
            [3] => ftps
            [4] => gopher
            [5] => http
            [6] => https
            [7] => imap
            [8] => imaps
            [9] => ldap
            [10] => ldaps
            [11] => pop3
            [12] => pop3s
            [13] => rtmp
            [14] => rtsp
            [15] => scp
            [16] => sftp
            [17] => smb
            [18] => smbs
            [19] => smtp
            [20] => smtps
            [21] => telnet
            [22] => tftp
        )

    [ares] => 1.15.0
    [ares_num] => 69376
    [libidn] => 
    [iconv_ver_num] => 0
    [libssh_version] => libssh2/1.8.0
    [brotli_ver_num] => 16777223
    [brotli_version] => 1.0.7
)
```

`PHP` version: `PHP Version => 7.3.2`

installed with `homebrew`.

I have tried almost all of the solutions here on SO, but still getting the same error. Do I need to download and compile `PHP` from source? Any clue/suggestion would be a huge help. Thanks.

Comment: Does it report this for all HTTP/2 sites or just one particular?

Comment: for all, I guess, I have tried to connect to 3 different ones, same..

Comment: @Mubin : did you received any solution for this error ?

Comment: @AkhileshKumar: unfortunately, no, I was developing an automated script at that time, so I move forward with Python Scrapy.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar to this and there was 2 things I needed to check for.

If you're using apache, in /etc/apache2/sites-available/[x].conf look for a line similar to this: Protocols h2 http/1.1

[x] = the name of the website's configuration file such as 00-default

For me I had Protocols h2 https://1.1 and that caused me to have the bug.

Alternative:
run this command on your server "grep -ir 'upgrade' /etc/apache2/"
Find the file that has the upgrade to http/2 and comment out the line.

This post helped me immensely: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/ssl-causing-website-to-not-load-at-all/39764/30

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and solve my problem.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```