# Sending a PUT request cURL in PHP 8.1 returns PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl request, which I can send from the cli like this:

```
curl -X 'PUT' \
  'https://XXX/endpiontY' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "value": "TestValue"
}'
```

(`curl --version` returns `curl 7.81.0`, so default is `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS`)

I am trying to send the same information with PHP, but I get

> HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

### My Setup

```
$json = array('value' => 'TestValue');
$json_string = json_encode($json);

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_string)
)

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    $error = curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

`$result` is always `false` so the error triggers with the above message shown.

### I tried

- I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59955444/1092632 `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);`

  - causes a timeout of the endpoint
- Using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);`

  - no change
- Adding `$headers[] = 'Connection: close';`

  - no change

Where am I wrong sending the PUT request? Any hint highly appreciated!

Comment: What version of curl is PHP using (`phpinfo()` or `curl_version()`)? It might be different than the cli binary you have.

Comment: `cURL Information 7.80.0` from `phpinfo()`

Comment: Have you tried adding a space to `'Content-Type:application/json'` (low probability of cause), or omitting the `Content-Length` header from your request (higher probability)?