# PHP retrieving JSON with Curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get some `JSON` with a Curl request. But either I get an error or a timeout.

I was trying with a simple call

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    if($curlReturn = curl_exec($curlSession) === false){
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curlSession);

        curl_close($curlSession);
    } else {

        }
```

But I get the error `Curl error: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)`

If I add following to use `HTTP 1.1` instead of `HTTP 2.0`, I just get a timeout.

```
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```

But if I paste the URL into the browser it works perfectly.

Comment: Related: [PHP Curl error HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56865217/2943403)

Comment: Yes it is related, but the solution in the other question does not work.

Answer (score 0):

1st check if your server supports `HTTP 2.0` or not and then try explicitly enabling the `HTTP 2.0` by using `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0` instead of `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1`.

If the problem continues then try updating the `CURL` library and increasing the timeout time:

```
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
```